# What does it mean when the extension of scalars is free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

In this post "ring" means "commutative ring with identity".

*Background:*

Let $\varphi : R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism. This gives us a functor $\varphi_!:= -\otimes_R S : \textbf{Mod}_R \to \textbf{Mod}_S$ often called the **extension of scalars**. This functor is left adjoint to the restriction of scalars, and therefore preserves colimits, and in particular direct sums. As a result, if $M$ is a free $R$-module, then $M \otimes_R S$ is a free $S$-module of the same rank.

*Question:*

I'm interested in the opposite question: What can be said about an $R$-module $M$ if $M \otimes_R S$ is a free $S$-module? What about the case when $M \otimes_R S$ is free of rank $1$?

Here's a possibly useful reframing of the question. The extension of scalars functor corresponds to the pullback of quasicoherent sheaves. The question then becomes, what can be said about a quasicoherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $\text{Spec}(R)$ if its pullback via $\text{Spec}(\varphi) : \text{Spec}(S) \to \text{Spec}(R)$ is free? What about the case when the pullback is free of rank $1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general nothing can be concluded: for example, if $S$ is a field then $M \otimes_R S$ is always free and this imposes no condition on $M$. (In this case $(-) \otimes_R S$ generally won't be faithful so it's not surprising that we lose information about $M$.)

If $\varphi : R \to S$ is [faithfully flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module#Faithfully_flat_ring_homomorphism) then [faithfully flat descent](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03O6) is available and a natural question to ask is whether $M \otimes_R S$ free implies that $M$ is locally free. According to the Stacks project this is [false in general](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05VF) and an open question if we additionally assume that $S$ is finitely presented over $R$ (asked on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155224/is-there-fppf-descent-of-locally-free-modules) with no answer), although apparently it holds if in addition $R$ is Noetherian or $M$ is finitely generated.

With either of these hypotheses, if $M \otimes_R S$ is free of rank $1$ then it follows that $M$ is locally free of rank $1$, or equivalently an invertible module / line bundle.

Comment: If your goal here is to prove that various characterizations of line bundles are equivalent you can get away with a bit less effort than this because you're free to choose many different values of $S$.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer! Do you happen to know about the case when $M$ is a projective $R$-module (and $M \otimes_R S$ is free of rank $1$)? I should have put this in the original question!

Comment: @Nate: again, with $\varphi : R \to S$ faithfully flat either of the above hypotheses it already follows that $M$ is invertible and hence projective.