# Reference Request: Extension of Scalars, Free and Projective Modules

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, modules

In the comments of this question:

[What does it mean when the extension of scalars is free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3845218/what-does-it-mean-when-the-extension-of-scalars-is-free),

it is mentioned that if $ \psi: R \rightarrow S $ is a faithfully flat ring homomorphism between commutative rings, with $R$ Noetherian and $M$ a finitely generated $R$ module then *if the extension of scalars $M \otimes_R S$ is a free $S$-module of rank one, $M$ is a (finitely generated) projective $R$-module of rank one*. Can anybody provide me with a reference for this fact? I have tried looking in Bourbaki's Commutative Algebra book and have searched on  the Stacks project but I could not find it.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You will find this in two steps in many books (say Matsumura). First, a module which becomes flat after a faithfully flat extension is flat. Second, a finitely generated flat module over a Noetherian ring is projective.